# jQuery slideToggle jump on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to slideToggle a  in a table with jQuery and it works in FF, OP, CHrome. Only IE (6,7,8) is giving me problems. It slides down perfectly down and up, but after the slide up animation is finished. The hidden  pops up in full height and then closes.

So I guess it must be somwhere inbetween when it switches from a minimal height to "display:none" that it appears for a short second.

The code is built dynamically but I'll try to give an example:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function toggleTr_{$dynamicID}() {
                $('#content_{$dynamicID}').slideToggle('slow');
                /* DO SOME OTHER STOFF LIKE COLOR CHANGES CSS CLASS CHANGES */
            }
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="list_{$dynamicID}" onclick="toggleTr_{$dynamicID}();" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <td> <!-- INFO HEADER --> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="content_{$dynamicID}" style="display:none;">
         <!-- INFO BODY HIDDEN --> 
        </div
    </td>
</tr>
```

Other problems here with slideToggle only descibed problems with padding, margin, or problems with the animation, but that all works.

Help is appreciated.

Thx, Spanky

Comment: You can't slide table-rows, at lest not cross-browser, not without visual artifacts like this, it's a re-flow calculation you're seeing.

Comment: re-flow calculation? Sorry but I don't understand. So only <div> boxes are supposed to be slidetoggled? That's why I created a <div> inside the tablerow that is hidden. And did not hide the row...

Comment: just checked the example from the last post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112726/how-to-slidetoggle-table-row-using-jquery which is kind of a clone of mine and this works.....but mine doesn'T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

It seems that only jquery's .slideUp() function is causing the problem when setting the height back to 0px. The bug only seems to appear when the browser is working in QuirksMode (HTML Transitional 4.01 DocType) and on IE. The solution I found [here](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2009/08/jquery-slideup-flickers-in-internet.html) is a replacement for .slideUp(). So instead of

```
targetElement.slideUp(speed,callBack)
```

you write

```
var h = target.height();
var cssHeight=target.css('height');
target.animate({ 
    height: '1px' }, speed, function() { 
    target.hide();
    target.height(h);
    target.css('height',cssHeight);
    callBack(); 
});
```

Thx to Siderite Zackwehdex wo also reported the bug to jQuery (http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5062), but they won't fix it. They said:

> you can just made sure that your document isn't in quirksmode (provide a proper doctype) - which is what we typically recommend when encountering this issue.

I also found a fix, or replacement for .slideToggle() for everyone who doesn't have the time or control over the HTML to fix it and make it "QuirksMode Clean".

[Here](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2009/4/21/Fixing-jQuerys-slideDown-effect-ie-Jumpy-Animation#c25072856-19B9-FE20-6C734F2EC43461CC) you'll find an explanation and function that works like a charm. The only change I had to make, was setting the height to '1px' so it won't jump open on the first run of .slideToggle() if elements are hidden from the beginning on.

So my working solution finally looks like this:

```
// this is a fix for the jQuery slide effects
  function slideToggle(el, bShow){
    var $el = $(el), height = $el.data("originalHeight"), visible = $el.is(":visible");

    // if the bShow isn't present, get the current visibility and reverse it
    if( arguments.length == 1 ) bShow = !visible;

    // if the current visiblilty is the same as the requested state, cancel
    if( bShow == visible ) return false;

    // get the original height
    if( !height ){
      // get original height
      height = $el.show().height();
      // update the height
      $el.data("originalHeight", height);
      // if the element was hidden, hide it again
      if( !visible ) $el.css({height: '1px'}).hide();
    }

    // expand the knowledge (instead of slideDown/Up, use custom animation which applies fix)
    if( bShow ){
      $el.show().animate({height: height}, {duration: 500});
    } else {
      $el.animate({height: '1px'}, {duration: 500, complete:function (){
          $el.hide();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248238/jquery-slidetoggle-hiccups-after-sliding-up-in-ie-8) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849398/why-does-this-jquery-slidetoggle-code-not-work) (on how to use the callback function).

You might also solve your problem in IE with the [zoom fix](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1354-The-Power-Of-ZOOM-Fixing-CSS-Issues-In-Internet-Explorer.htm).

Comment: tried the first one, adding a <p> between the <td> and the <div> in the <td> didn't work..... on to the next....

Comment: now I tried putting the javascript I excecuted into the callback -> didn't help, I added the zoom CSS -> didn't work, tried to build an example that also jumps -> didn't work......