# jQuery slideToggle() moves

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a slideToggle that shows/hides a table.

jQuery

```
$("#featMoreInfo").click(function() {    
    $("#featben2").slideToggle('slow');
    var txt = $(this).text() == '+ More Info' ? '- Minimize' : '+ More Info';
    $(this).text(txt);
});
$("#featMoreInfo2").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    $("#featben2").slideToggle('slow');
    $("#featMoreInfo").text('+ More Info');
});
```

I have a javascript tooltip in some of the columns. Occationally whenever you click `+ More Info` the alignment gets thrown off. Has anyone had this issue before?

[image: Sometimes Good Slide]

[image: Sometimes Bad Slide]

Comment: That's probably CSS related...

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with jQuery, http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/#comment-82454830, its due to jQuery being unable to calculate and render their correct height of table row / cells.

I've had this problem in a project and ended up using another effect as it was unstable and so wasn't fit for production.

Did a quick search and found a post by spankmaster79 who answered this question and suggested a fix so this post might be worth a read.
[jQuery slideToggle jump on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004480/jquery-slidetoggle-jump-on-close)

Comment: Thank you, really great advice. I had no idea about this.